# How to remove NaN in subtracting?

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, regression, subtraction

I am trying to perform subtraction in python. This is a simple task when performed in excel but I want to do this in jupyter notebook.

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

#Read X1 anomaly
X1= pd.read_csv (r'file\X1.csv') 
X1 = pd.DataFrame(X1,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
X1=  X1[X1['Year'].between(1984,2020, inclusive="both")]
#X1 = X1["Mar"].describe()
#print (X1)

#Read X2 anomaly
X2= pd.read_csv (r'file\X2.csv') 
X2 = pd.DataFrame(X2,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
X2=  X2[X2['Year'].between(1984,2020, inclusive="both")]
#X2 = X2["Mar"].describe()
#print (X2)

X1 = X1["Mar"] 
X2 = X2["Mar"]
#### my goal is to remove transform X2 by removing their line of fit 
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X1.values.reshape(-1,1), X2)
Trend=regr.coef_*X1+regr.intercept_
X3=np.subtract(X2,Trend)
print (X3)
```

And here is the data [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18AaLBFi5KLx16iSvBPClxzTF7lZPaI1q?usp=sharing). I want to remove the linear between X1 and X2 so I performed regression of X1 and X2 then I want to subtract the trend line from X2 to make it X3. However, there is a lot of NaN in X3. Please help me on what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer after experimenting with the codes and I want to share them with you in case someone is experiencing similar issue.

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X1.values.reshape(-1,1), X2)
Trend=regr.coef_*X1+regr.intercept_
X3=X2-np.array(Trend)
print (X3)
```

Notice what I did in the subtraction formula. Thank you.